# Append a large li to ul: best way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a li that has numerous nested divs. I am appending to a ul as follows:

```
     $("ul#List").append('<li><div>....many more nested divs...</li>');
```

the structure of the li is the same as the other lis in ul but i have to modify some elements.

My question is simply am I doing it wrong by manually writing out the entire structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please folllow this,

provide class/id to li which you want to append

suppose you want to append

```
<li id='templi'><div>......</div><li>
```

then

```
var lihtml = jQuery('#templi').clone();

jQuery("ul#List").append(lihtml);
```

revert if you have any problem, i think it works

Answer (score 3):

If it follows a template (standard HTML with spots to accept variables) you might have a `build(data)` function that takes in your dataset and builds an html string. It would be a lot more maintainable in the long run, also reusable.

Resig has his own templating shebang here:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

So your function (unrelated to the above link) might look like this:

```
var myObject = {
    name : "Alex",
    occupation : "Developer",
    faveFormat : "JSON"
}

function buildHTML(obj) {
    var name = obj.name;
    var occupation = obj.occupation;
    var faveFormat = obj.faveFormat;

    var resultHTML = [];

    resultHTML.push('<li><div>');
    resultHTML.push("My name is" + name);
    //etc etc
    resultHTML.push('</div></li>');
    var doneHTML = resultHTML.join(" ");
    return doneHTML;
}
```

Try it out!